# JAVA ECLIPSE: Get paths of my jar/zip-resource

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, reference, resources

I have a problem with my application in eclipse.
I want to create a runnable jar out of my application, but i need to know how to access a resource.
My resource is another jar/zip (it only has text-files included). But I am not even sure if it is a resource yet. Do i have to do somthing to make my jar a resource?

I used this methods to get a list of all my resources, but it seems that every resource is the "/bin" directory. That makes no sense to me.

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResources("./");
```

I can't find my jar file i want to use as resource. What should i do?

I hope someone understands my problem, because my mother tongue isn't Englisch.

Greetings
Stefan

Comment: It is not possible to load classes from jars inside jars.

Comment: Actually the jar-resource i want to use has no classes. It only has text-files. And i want to use them. I don't even know how to use a simple textfile alone as a resource ^^"

Comment: did you verify that the `inside.jar` is really inside `outside.jar`?

Comment: First of all, i want the "getResources()"-method to work inside my Eclipse project. Not even in my Jar-File.

I see my Resource-Jar-File inside my project, but i am not sure, what the right way is, to add it.
-inside a source-directory?
-inside a simple directory?
-as a referenced library?

Comment: Ok, i solved it.
I use getResource() now, because i have only one resource.
This worked, when i found out how to do the path right, i few minutes ago.^^